# How to add a searchbar that changes api address?

Tags: reactjs, api, search

I am creating a basic news app as practice to learn React.  I have learned a bit about creating search bars but I am unable to figure out how to implement them properly.  For this project, I would just like to allow the user to enter a country into the search bar and have it change the URL.  The country is currently called in useFetch in TopHeadlinesUS.js.  Can anyone help me figure this out?

**useFetch.js**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"; import axios from "axios";

function useFetch(url) {   const [data, setData] = useState(null);   const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);   const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    axios
      .get(url)
      .then((response) => {
        setData(response.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        setError(err);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        setLoading(false);
      });   }, [url]);

  return { data, loading, error }; } export default useFetch;
```

**TopHeadlinesUS.js**

```
import "../App.css";
import useFetch from "./useFetch";
import { useState } from "react";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import { Row, Col, Container } from "react-bootstrap";
import { FaBeer } from "react-icons/fa";
import { Puff } from "react-loading-icons";
import LoadingScreen from "./LoadingScreen";

import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Test = () => {
  const [country, setCountry] = useState("us");

  const {
    data: start,
    loading,
    error,
  } = useFetch(
    `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=${country}&apiKey=712a8c0fa12d406c8f710f1d01b47dd8`
  );

  console.log(start, "after fetch");

  if (loading) return <h1>{<LoadingScreen />}</h1>;

  if (error) return console.log(error);

  const styles = {
    cardImage: {
      objectFit: "cover",
    },
  };

  return (
    <div className="TopHeadlinesUS">
      <Container fluid>
        {/*Row1*/}
        <Row>
          <Col>
            <Link to={{ pathname: start?.articles[0].url }} target="_blank">
              <center>
                <img variant="top" src={start?.articles[0].urlToImage} />
              </center>
            </Link>
            <Link to={{ pathname: start?.articles[0].url }} target="_blank">
              <h2>{start?.articles[0].title.replace(/-[^,]+$/, "")}</h2>
            </Link>
          </Col>

          <Col>
            <Link to={{ pathname: start?.articles[1].url }} target="_blank">
              <center>
                <img alt="" variant="top" src={start?.articles[1].urlToImage} />
              </center>
            </Link>
            <Link>
              <h2>{start?.articles[1].title.split("-")[0]}</h2>
            </Link>
          </Col> 
....
```

Answer (score 0):

you can implement your search like this:

https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-babbage-f8q90e?file=/src/App.js

I just created an example for your input component.
You can try to use `debounce` function to make it more efficient.

Good luck!